# Why are some elements of this OpenStreetMap tree being skipped by iterparse?

Tags: python, xml, openstreetmap, iterparse

I have an OSM file that captures a small neighborhood.  http://pastebin.com/xeWJsPeY

I have Python code that does a lot of extra parsing, but an example of the main problem can be seen here:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as CET
osmfile = open('osm_example.osm','r')
for event, elem in CET.iterparse(osmfile,events = ('start',)):
    if elem.tag == 'way':
        if elem.get('id') == "21850789":
            for child in elem:
                print CET.tostring(child,encoding='utf-8')
    elem.clear()
```

Here, and elsewhere, I noticed that the tags for a specific entry are missing (where tag is an element that looks like `<tag k="highway" v="residential" />`.  All of the `<nd .../>` elements were read correctly, as far as I can see.

One other thing I noticed when processing the files is that when I use `tostring()` on an element with a `'way'` tag, if there are errors with the `<tag .../>` elements being read, it didn't append a newline to the end of it.  e.g., when running

```
for event, elem in CET.iterparse(osmfile,events = ('start',)):
    if elem.tag == 'way':
        print CET.tostring(elem,encoding='utf-8')
    elem.clear()
```

The output for an entry with missing `<tag .../>` elements is

```
<nd ref="235476200" />
  <nd ref="1865868598" /></way><way changeset="12727901" id="21853023" timestamp="2012-08-14T15:23:13Z" uid="451048" user="bbmiller" version="8" visible="true">
  <nd ref="1865868557" />
```

versus one that is formed just fine,

```
 <tag k="tiger:zip_left" v="60061" />
  <tag k="tiger:zip_right" v="60061" />
 </way>
 <way changeset="15851022" id="21874389" timestamp="2013-04-24T16:33:28Z" uid="451693" user="bot-mode" version="3" visible="true">
  <nd ref="235666887" />
  <nd ref="235666891" />
```

What is the issue that is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be searching for child elements in response to the `start` event. But the child elements have not necessarily been read yet.

Consider this fragment:

```xml
<a>foo<b/></a>
```

The `start` event occurs after the parser has read `<a>`, but before it reads `foo` and, more to the point, before it reads `<b/>`. As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) says:

> > Note iterparse() only guarantees that it has seen the “>” character of a starting tag when it emits a “start” event, so the attributes are defined, but the contents of the text and tail attributes are undefined at that point. The same applies to the element children; they may or may not be present.
> >
> > If you need a fully populated element, look for “end” events instead.

So, you might get the behavior you want with this code:

```
for event, elem in CET.iterparse(osmfile,events = ('end',)):
```

Comment: I used 'end' and changed the way I cleared elements.  I avoided 'end' before because I wanted to clear the children last, but I was able to make a workaround for that.  Thanks.